# Update with multiple condition Xamarin.Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

Hey good day I am new to Firebase Database or Document Type DB, I am using firebasedatabase (https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) My Problem is updating specific node with multiple condition with a statement similar to this.

```
 UPDATE account_profile SET homecity = 'NY' WHERE email='xjake@yahoo.com' AND uid = '0001';
```

The author does not provide much example only this one

// add new item directly to the specified location (this will overwrite whatever data already exists at that location)

```
await firebase
  .Child("dinosaurs")
  .Child("t-rex")
  .PutAsync(new Dinosaur());
```

My firebasedb:

```
{
      "account_profile" : 
    {
        "-Kk5Xv3E0kqlh6HJSGJ4" : {
          "email" : "xjake@yahoo.com",
          "homecity" : "Iligan, Lanao del Norte",
          "uid" : "0001"
        },
        "-Kk5dKkgMGkFZ7oJZzf7" : {
          "email" : "qjake@yahoo.com",
          "homecity" : "Mabalacat, Pampanga",
          "uid" : "0002"
        },
        "-Kk5dTV0oOezkCm8Jb6l" : {
          "email" : "ljake@yahoo.com",
          "homecity" : "Cabuyao, Laguna",
          "uid" : "0003"
        },
        "-Kk5dtABQUEF4LIuOXvx" : {
          "email" : "njake@yahoo.com",
          "homecity" : "Davao City, Davao del Sur",
          "uid" : "0002"
        },
        "-Kk5enNz7MX6V2gnmcza" : {
          "email" : "bjake@yahoo.com",
          "homecity" : "Iligan, Lanao del Norte",
          "uid" : "0004"
        },
        "-Kk8wzWtzCyAWOxxpyWX" : {
          "email" : "jake@yahoo.com",
          "homecity" : "Iligan, Lanao del Norte",
          "uid" : "0005"
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks and Good Day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems what you like is [Update specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields), but this method is built in the native firebase for Android lib, I couldn't find such a method in your [FirebaseDatabase.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) lib.

So, to solve your issue, you may:

1. Install the [Xamarin.Firebase.Database](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/master/firebase-database) package and try the `UpdateChildrenAsync` or `UpdateChildren` method of this package. This package is like the native SDK for Xamarin.Android.
2. Or, download all the data in that node and parse them to a `List` of your data type `Dinosaur`, then modify the list item you wanted and finally use the `PutAsync` method of `FirebaseDatabase.net` lib to overwrite the old data in that node.