# Xamarin.forms- Firebase database update with multiple values (Android)

Tags: xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms (Android portion) app, I using firebase database for storing some data.In my db I have a user data which contains userid, Email, Latitude and longitude. I can Update and retrieve these data.

**My Problem**

I am trying to upload users latitude and longitude against the  Latitude and longitude fields in my db. Currently I can update the fields, which will overwrite the existing data. What I want is instead of overwriting each latitude and longitude entry , it will store as new record. Because I want list the latitudes and longitudes in a listview. Since all my update and retrieve operations are happening in shared code. But this particular insert need to be happen in service. So how to insert each latitude and longitude as a new entry instead of replacing the old one?

**My Model Class**

```
public class Person
    {           
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public string Latitude{ get; set; }
        public string Longitude{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Normal data Updation**

```
  await firebaseHelper.UpdatePerson(Convert.ToInt32(empid),email, latitude, longitude);
```

**Firebase helper portion**

```
 public async Task UpdatePerson(int personId,  string emailid, string latitude, string longitude)
        {
            var toUpdatePerson = (await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .OnceAsync<Person>()).Where(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();

            await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .Child(toUpdatePerson.Key)
              .PutAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId,EmailID=emailid,Latitude=latitude,Longitude=longitude });
    }
```

**EDIT**:

As per leo's suggestion,  I added latitude and longitude as list in my model class. Initially in my Person creation, I added like this in `FirebaseHelper.cs`

```
 public async Task UpdatePerson(int personId, string name, string address, string phonenumber, string emailid, string password, bool status)
        {
            var toUpdatePerson = (await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .OnceAsync<Person>()).Where(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();

            await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .Child(toUpdatePerson.Key)
              .PutAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Name = name,Address=address,PhoneNumber=phonenumber,EmailID=emailid,Password=password,Status=status });
        }
```

I am trying to update latitude and longitude from android service. My android service is like this.

```
[Service]
class LocationService : Service
{
    internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";
    internal static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
    FirebaseHelperClass firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelperClass();
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
    /*
     * This service will run until stopped explicitly because we are returning sticky
     */
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Location tracking started", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        StartServiceInForeground();
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
    /*
     * When our service is to be destroyed, show a Toast message before the destruction.
     */
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Location tracking stopped", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }

      void StartServiceInForeground()
    {

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
        {

            try
            {               
                 // Here I am calling the Firebase Helper class
                 firebaseHelper.UpdatePersonLocation(2,null,null);
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            return true; 
        });


        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

            var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Pedometer Service Channel", NotificationImportance.High)
            {
                Description = "Foreground Service Channel"
            };

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            var notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetContentTitle("SR Associates")
            .SetContentText("Tracking moode is on")
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.user)                
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .Build();
             StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }


    }

}
```

My latitude and longitude update portion on `FirebaseHelper`

```
  public async Task UpdatePersonLocation(int personId, string latitude, string longitude)
        {
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            var toUpdatePerson = (await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .OnceAsync<Person>()).Where(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();

            List<string> latitudes = toUpdatePerson.Object.Latitude;
            List<string> longitudes = toUpdatePerson.Object.Longitude;
            latitudes.Add(location.Latitude.ToString());
            longitudes.Add(location.Longitude.ToString());
            await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .Child(toUpdatePerson.Key)
              .PutAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Latitude = latitudes, Longitude = longitudes });
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to 1 person with multiple Latitude and Longitude.

If yes,Maybe you could define the `Latitude` and `Longitude` as a `List`.(as there is no `updateChildren` method such as in native firebase for Android lib,you could look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991688/10768653) )

```
public class Person
{           
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Latitude{ get; set; }
    public List<string> Longitude{ get; set; }
}
```

then use the `PutAsync` method of `FirebaseDatabase.net` lib to overwrite the old data in the nodes `Latitude` and `Latitude`.

```
 public async Task UpdatePerson(int personId, string latitude, string longitude)
    {
        var toUpdatePerson = (await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>()).Where(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();

        List<string> latitudes= toUpdatePerson.Object.Latitude;
        List<string> longitudes= toUpdatePerson.Object.Longitude;
        latitudes.Add(latitude);
        longitudes.Add(longitude);
        await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .Child(toUpdatePerson.Key)
          .PutAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Latitude= latitudes,Longitude = longitudes});
    }
```

**Update**

add Person ：

```
public async Task AddPerson(int personId,string emailId, string latitude, string longitude)
    {
        List<string> latitudes = new List<string>();
        List<string> longitudes = new List<string>();
        latitudes.Add(latitude);
        longitudes.Add(longitude);
        await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .PostAsync(new Person() { PersonId=personId, EmailID = emailId, Latitude = latitudes,Longitude=longitudes });
    }
```

the effect 
in Realtime Database is like below:

[image]

after i call `AddPerson` method :

[image]

then after i call `UpdatePerson` method:

[image]

Comment: Thanks leo for the reply. Let me check

Comment: Bro sorry for late reply. I actually tried your code on my android service. But it never hit on   await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .Child(toUpdatePerson.Key)
          .PutAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Latitude= latitudes,Longitude = longitudes});om

Comment: Is there any changes to be done when we try this on android service?

Comment: As i could not see the complete code，i will show my codes that i add and update the person,you could check it.

Comment: It doesnt adding latitudes and longitude fields in console. I can only see name, id etc except latitude and longitude

Comment: Bro,May I ask one more doubt? In order to update latitude and longitude only, should I pass the other parameters such as Name, email id etc? Currently I am only passign person ID , latitude and longiude on update. But it removes my other parameters like Name , email id etc in console

Comment: You should pass the other parameters，it acturely replace the data

Comment: Ok bro. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is record periodic data of all your users in a locations table.

So you are not doing an Update anymore (Put async call), but you want to Create/Insert a new row (Post async call) every time. This way you have the historical data of all the locations the user has been.

Seems like you already been following a tutorial like this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/ , so if you scroll to the Insert section, it detailed how you added a new record. Now you have to just keep adding records

Comment: Thanks saamer for the reply.Let me check

Comment: Welcome anytime

Answer (score 0):

```
 Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
                        {

                            try
                            {

                                var isupdates = FirebaseHelper.UpdateUsernew(name, null, null, Address);
                            }

                            catch (Exception)
                            {

                            }

                            return true;
                        });



public static async Task<bool> UpdateUsernew(string email, string latitude, string longitude, string Address)
    {
        try
        {
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            var toUpdateUser = (await firebase
            .Child("usersTable")
            .OnceAsync<Users>()).Where(a => a.Object.Username == email).FirstOrDefault();

            double latitudes = toUpdateUser.Object.Position.Latitude;
            double longitudes = toUpdateUser.Object.Position.Longitude;
            latitudes= location.Latitude;
            longitudes=location.Longitude;

            await firebase
            .Child("usersTable")
            .Child(toUpdateUser.Key)
            .PutAsync(new Users() { Username = email, Address = Address, Position = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(latitudes, longitudes) });
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
            return false;
        }
    }


public Position Position { get; set; }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQg90.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).