# Xamarin.Forms: How to update only one specific value in many childs in Firebase Realtime?

Tags: c#, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I am using the Nuget from Firebase Database [dot] Net in Xamarin.Forms.

I want to edit the value that is Idproceso and the orderId, without having to reload all the values, since the problem that it generates is that all the objects are updated and are filled based on the first object, that is, all the values are duplicated It contains the first object, appendix captures of what happens in the database.

**[This is before updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpbuW.png)**

**[This is after updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKtmD.png)**

For this I am using the following code

```
public static async Task<bool> UpdateDetail()
    {
        try
        {

            var toCount = (await firebase
            .Child("DetallePedidos")
            .Child(Preferences.Get("email", string.Empty))
            .Child("Elementos")
            .OnceAsync<AgregarCarrito>()).Where(x => x.Object.Idproceso == false).ToList().Count();

            var result = (await GetShoppinCartItems()).Select(item =>
            new AgregarCarrito
            {
                orderId = item.orderId,
                ProductName = item.ProductName,
                CustomerId = item.CustomerId,
                Price = item.Price,
                TotalAmount = item.TotalAmount,
                ProductId = item.ProductId,
                Qty = item.Qty,
                Valor = item.Valor,
                imageUrl = item.imageUrl,
                Idproceso = item.Idproceso
                //Key = item.Key

            }).Where(x => x.Idproceso == false).FirstOrDefault();

            for (int i = 0; i < toCount; i++)
            {


                var toUpdateItems = (await firebase
            .Child("DetallePedidos")
            .Child(Preferences.Get("email", string.Empty))
            .Child("Elementos")
            .OnceAsync<AgregarCarrito>()).Where(x => x.Object.Idproceso == false).FirstOrDefault();

              await firebase
            .Child("DetallePedidos")
            .Child(Preferences.Get("email", string.Empty))
            .Child("Elementos")
            .Child(toUpdateItems.Key)           
            .PutAsync(new AgregarCarrito
            {

                ProductName = result.ProductName,
                CustomerId = result.CustomerId,
                Price = result.Price,
                TotalAmount = result.TotalAmount,
                ProductId = result.ProductId,
                Qty = result.Qty,
                Idproceso = true,
                imageUrl = result.imageUrl,
                Valor = result.Valor,
                orderId = Preferences.Get("idOrder", string.Empty)


            });
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems what you like is [Update specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields), but this method is built in the native firebase for Android lib, I couldn't find such a method in your [FirebaseDatabase.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) lib.

So, to solve your issue, you may:

1. Install the [Xamarin.Firebase.Database](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/master/firebase-database) package and try the `UpdateChildrenAsync` or `UpdateChildren` method of this package. This package is like the native SDK for Xamarin.Android.
2. Or, download all the data in that node , then modify them as you wanted and finally use the `PutAsync` method of `FirebaseDatabase.net` lib to overwrite the old data in that node.

this is refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991688/10768653)

**Update** :

you could get the old value by the key (e.g `-M7L...`  in the image above).

like：

```
//i think your customerId should be unique
var toUpdate = (await firebase
      .Child("Elementos")
      .OnceAsync<YourModel>()).Where(a => a.Object.CustomerId == customerId).FirstOrDefault(); 
// modify your data (toUpdate is your old object value)
...(e.g. toUpdate.Price = 100; toUpdate.Qty = 6;.... )

//update the new value
await firebase
      .Child("Elementos")
      .Child(toUpdate.Key)
      .PutAsync(new YourModel() {...});
```

Comment: But if it is a list of objects, how can I download and modify?